# Finding the longest dictionary word at the end of a string

Tags: php, mysql, optimization, string, dictionary

I'm looking for the best way to search a string of alphabetical characters for the longest possible dictionary word at the end of the string.

**Example:** For the string `qbehugejackhammer` the result should be `jackhammer` instead of `hammer`.

One way to do this somewhat efficiently would be storing the words in reversed form in an indexed table and iterating them one letter at a time until it no longer matches anything:

```
SELECT word FROM dictionary WHERE word LIKE 'remmahkca%';
SELECT word FROM dictionary WHERE word LIKE 'remmahkcaj%'; # last match
SELECT word FROM dictionary WHERE word LIKE 'remmahkcaje%';
```

That looks and feels like a hack and is most likely not the optimal solution. Is there any faster and/or nicer way to do this? My tools of choice are PHP and MySQL but if some other language or DBMS suits my needs better I'm all ears.

Comment: The optimal approach will depend on how many times you intend to perform this search. Are you iterating a structure containing a few? dozens? hundreds? thousands? of words that need to be examined in this manner?

Comment: I don't have time for a complete answer, but check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_word_graph

Comment: @Tim: This is for a full English dictionary and will be called approximately once per minute for every active site user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick hacky answer: load your dictionary into a `map` or whatever the php equivalent data structure is (An english dictionary is only ~50k words, fits in RAM v easily, and a map is much, much faster to query than a DB call). Then iterate forwards 1 character at a time, testing each substring against the map until you find a match.

Depending on how long your strings are, you could optimise by first checking the longest word in the dictionary (you can get this during the dictionary load) and starting the appropriate distance in. I'm sure there are other similar optimisations you could employ too (longest by start character etc)

**Edit:** "map" should be "set".

Comment: The PHP equivalent for hashmaps is simply arrays, as the keys can be alphanumeric. I believe alphabetic keys are internally hashed and used in integer form. With proper caching this may be the method I'll be going for. Also, checking the maximum length against the longest dictionary word is a really good point.

Comment: @Kaivosukeltaja: actually I meant "set" not "map": you don't need a key-value structure, just a key structure. Although of course use a map if a set is not available in php

Answer (score 4):

It may sound slightly evil, but you'll probably get best performance by loading your dictionary into an array in the shape of a dictionary tree, but in reverse word order, for example:

```
array(
    'r' => array(
        'u' => array(), // -- words ending in 'ur' would end up in here
        'a' => array(), // -- words ending in 'ar' would end up here
        'e' => array( // -- words ending in 'er' would end up in here
            'm' => array(
                'm' => array(
                      // -- jackhammer will be kept further up here
```

Then seeking up.

```
$reverseWord = ""; // -- Incoming 'word' string goes here, in reverse.
$dictionary = [structure above];
$dictionaryPosition = $dictionary;
$dictionaryHistory = "";

for( $i = 0, $l = strlen($reverseWord); $i < $l; $i++ ) {
    $char = $reverseWord[$i];

    // -- If this character doesn't exist in this dictionary position, we've reached the end
    if( !isset($dictionaryPosition[$char]) )
        break;

    // -- log this character
    $dictionaryHistory = $char . $dictionaryHistory;

    // -- Climb up the tree
    $dictionaryPosition = $dictionaryPosition[$char];
}

// -- $dictionaryHistory now contains the word you're looking for.
```

Each array should contain no more than 26 entries (assuming alphabetic characters only), so you're looking at doing, at most, 26*n lookups of a single character each.  Even with a word depth of 20 characters, that's infinitely better than iterating through a list of 50k words several times.

Comment: I am very sure that this approach will be slower than just storing all dictionary words in a hash table and performing lookup on it.

Comment: With C style static size arrays this would definitely be wicked fast. I'm a bit concerned about the speed of PHP's array creation and having to rebuild the array for each request. Of course the array could be serialized and cached but I think unserializing means re-instantiating the whole 50k bunch of arrays too?

Answer (score 4):

You could start by searching for a word that matches the entire string and keep removing letters at the beginning of the string until you find a match:

```
SELECT word FROM dictionary WHERE word = 'qbehugejackhammer'; --no match
SELECT word FROM dictionary WHERE word = 'behugejackhammer'; --no match
SELECT word FROM dictionary WHERE word = 'ehugejackhammer'; --no match
SELECT word FROM dictionary WHERE word = 'hugejackhammer'; --no match
--...
SELECT word FROM dictionary WHERE word = 'jackhammer'; --found it!
```

Comment: That's a good approach, but if the string is very long it could cause a lot of unnecessary queries. Limiting the string's length to the longest dictionary word's length as suggested in the other answers would of course eliminate the possibility of extremely long iterations.

Answer (score 2):

Load the dictionary a PHP array. For every input word, use `in_array` ([link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)) on successively smaller substrings as explained below till you find a match.

For example, consider your input `qbehugejackhammer`. First, search the array for `qbehugejackhammer`, then for `behugejackhammer`, then for `ehugejackhammer` and so on till you find a match. You can stop as soon as you find the first match.

Comment: outch. Using in_array will be dead slow. Instead use an associative array (word => true). That way you'll have O(1) lookup instead of O(n).

Comment: Right, `array_key_exists()` would be a better choice. Also, like you pointed out, the dictionary words should be the keys and not values.